# Herança no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, classes, herança, dataannotations

Estou agora lendo sobre herança entre domínios no EF. Me deparei com esse exemplo:

```
public abstract class BillingDetail
{
    public int BillingDetailId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

[Table("BankAccounts")]
public class BankAccount : BillingDetail
{
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string Swift { get; set; }
}

[Table("CreditCards")]
public class CreditCard : BillingDetail
{
    public int CardType { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryMonth { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryYear { get; set; }
}

public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BillingDetail> BillingDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Reparei que só as classes derivadas recebem a anotação `[Table("NameTable")]`. Supondo então que a propriedade `Owner` deve ser obrigatória nas classes derivadas, ( `[Required]` ), e que também deve ter seu tamanho de caracteres limitado a 50, ( `[MaxLenght(50)]` ). Nesses casos a anotação ficam na classe pai, correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correto. Partindo do princípio que deseja ter uma tabela para cada tipo. Nem poderia ser diferente, já que as propriedades não aparecem nas classes filhas.

Claro que o resto da modelagem precisa estar certa também :)

Comment: Mas ainda assim a classe pai pode ficar sem a anotação `[Table]` ? Ou seja, só com as anotações nas propriedades.

Comment: Sim, não precisa da anotação, será criada uma tabela para ela. Tem um exemplo em TPT (que parece ser o que deseja) pra ver como é: https://datatellblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/12/inheritance-modelling-patterns-with-entity-framework-6-code-first/

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a configuração do [Entity Framework Fluent](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/11/28/composing-entity-framework-fluent-configurations.aspx) isso fica bem claro, você deve colocar essas configurações detalhadas no arquivo de configurações herdando da classe [EntityTypeConfiguration](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/11/28/composing-entity-framework-fluent-configurations.aspx).

*Observe:*

```
public class BankAccountConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<BankAccount>
{
    public BankAccountConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("BankAccounts");

        Property(c => c.BankName)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.Swift)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

public class CreditCardConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CreditCard>
{
    public CreditCardConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("CreditCards");

        Property(c => c.CardType)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.ExpiryMonth)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.ExpiryYear)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

public class BillingDetailConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<BillingDetail>
{
    public BillingDetailConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("BillingDetail");

        HasKey(c => c.BillingDetailId);

        Property(c => c.BillingDetailId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.Number)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.Owner)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

*Configurando a classe DbContext*

```
public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{

    public InheritanceMappingContext()
        :base("Conn1")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<BillingDetail> BillingDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BillingDetailConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BankAccountConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CreditCardConfiguration());
    }
}
```

*Gravando Informações:*

```
InheritanceMappingContext c = new InheritanceMappingContext();

BankAccount b = new BankAccount();
b.BankName = "N";
b.Number = "1";
b.Owner = "O";
b.Swift = "O";

c.BillingDetails.Add(b);
c.SaveChanges();
```

***Nesse caso em especifico foi criado um tabela para cada classe de configuração e as regras colocadas em cada classe de configuração, isso melhora a leitura de código, mas, nada impede em usar as anotações também***

*Acredito que assim a herança fica bem clara e sua pergunta afirmação está correta, onde as configurações ficam cada uma no seu lugar de origem.*

*Usando* [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[Table("BillingDetail")]
public abstract class BillingDetail
{
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BillingDetailId { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

[Table("BankAccounts")]
public class BankAccount : BillingDetail
{
    [Required()]
    public string BankName { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string Swift { get; set; }
}

[Table("CreditCards")]
public class CreditCard : BillingDetail
{
    [Required()]
    public int CardType { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string ExpiryMonth { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string ExpiryYear { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Pois é, estou ciente que fluente api é o top das galáxias quando o assunto é EF. Mas como estou entrando no mundo .net agora, nesse primeiro momento estou dando preferência para DataAnotations.
Quero me familiarizar com as duas formas.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva fantástico realmente e parabéns pela seu estudo, é sempre bom saber as maneiras possiveis e utilizar conforme for sua necessidade, vou colocar com DataAnotations

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva fiz a alterações e coloque com  DataAnnotations https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx